# Determinants Proof Problem

Tags: trigonometry, determinant

The question pertains to Trigonometric element in Determinants. 
[image: To Prove that]

I tried but could not get RHS.

Comment: Please replace the link to an image of text by actual text so it can be found using the search and is accessible to people using screen readers etc. Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In order to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Answer (score 1):

$$D=\sin(C-B)+\sin(A-C)+\sin(B-A)$$

Set $C-B=2X$ etc.  $X+Y+Z=0,X+Y=-Z,$

$\cos(X+Y)=\cos(-Z)=?$

$\sin(X+Y)=\sin(-Z)=?$

$$=\sin2X+\sin2Y+\sin2Z$$

$$=2\sin(X+Y)\cos(X-Y)+2\sin Z\cos Z$$

$$=-2\sin Z\cos(X-Y)+2\sin Z\cos(X+Y)$$

$$=-2\sin Z[\cos(X-Y)-\cos(X+Y)]$$

$$=-2\sin Z[2\sin X\sin Y]$$